# $http is not working with Angularjs and Expressjs

Tags: angularjs, express

I'm trying to go through the tutorials on docs.angularjs.org, but use node/express for the backend. Unfortunately, I'm not able to get $http in my controller working.

The following is straight from the [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05):

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <script src="js/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <!--Sidebar content-->

        Search: <input ng-model="query">
        Sort by:
        <select ng-model="orderProp">
          <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
          <option value="age">Newest</option>
        </select>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <!--Body content-->

        <ul class="phones">
          <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
            <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
            <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**controllers.js**

```
'use strict';
/* Controllers */
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.phones = data;
  });
  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}]);
```

The rest is not from the tutorial:

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
    });
};
```

**server.js**

```
// modules =================================================
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var mongoose       = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

// configuration ===========================================

// config files
//var db = require('./config/db');

var port = process.env.PORT || 50000; // set our port
// mongoose.connect(db.url); // connect to our mongoDB database (commented out after you enter in your own credentials)

// get all data/stuff of the body (POST) parameters
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request. simulate DELETE/PUT
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users

// routes ==================================================
require('./app/routes')(app); // pass our application into our routes

// start app ===============================================
app.listen(port);   
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);           // shoutout to the user
exports = module.exports = app;                         // expose app
```

If I just declare $scope.phones to be the JSON without using $http, then I get the expected result. What am I doing wrong such that $http is not being invoked?

Comment: phones/phones.json have to be a file or api on server side. check out this generator - https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack - there is full working api calls.